# Not able to append an img tag to a p tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a complete beginner in JavaScript and I am trying to create a script which is fired when a "file input" element of the page gets a file loaded. The script should basically create a `p` element, insert in it an `img`, a `innerText` and a `span`, hence append all this into a form. Everything works fine with the script below, except for the `img`:

```
function visualUploadFile() {

 var obj = document.getElementById("hidden_file").files[0].name;

    //create p object to append to the form
    var pobj = document.createElement("p");
    pobj.className = "form_line_file";

    //nest icon inside the object
    var imgico = document.createElement("img");
    imgico.src = "load-ico.png";

    //append img to the p - THE OBJECT IS NOT APPENDED
    pobj.appendChild(imgico);

    //nest file name as inner Text to the p
    pobj.innerText = obj;

    //create span object to write "rimuovi"
    var spanobj = document.createElement("span");
    spanobj.className = "rimuovi_file";
    spanobj.innerHTML = "rimuovi";

    //append span to the p
    pobj.appendChild(spanobj);

    //get form and append p child
    var bigForm = document.getElementById("offerta_form");
    bigForm.appendChild(pobj);
}
```

Here is the HTML after the script has been executed, as you can see only the img is missing:

```
<p class="form_line_file"> <!--p object correctly appended to the form-->
    Immagine.png <!--inner Text properly appended-->
    <span class="rimuovi_file"> <!--span object correctly appended-->
        rimuovi
    </span>
</p>
```

Probably is a stupid mistake, but I'm not being able to sort it out. Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong not to be able to get the img appended as for the span?

Comment: firstly you need to append the pobj then only append imgico to pobj...

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal tried it, not working :/

Comment: you are rewriting the content of `pobj` in `pobj.innerText = obj;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are adding file name label is incorrect. Setting `innerText` overwrites image. Instead of

```
pobj.innerText = obj;
```

try this:

```
pobj.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj));
```

Comment: it was, indeed, a very "beginner" mistake. Answer accepted, thanks!